# Display Position of an Item in a List

Tags: c#

I am working with a link list. The list is brought up on the form load (size, height, stock, price) displayed in a multiline textbox called `textBoxResults`. I have three button called `First`, `Next` and `Last`. Naming convention is straightforward, button `First` click displays first tree,   `Next`, displays each item after first through each button click and  `Last` button shows the last item on list. `First` works fine but `Second` only shows the following item after first and gives up, `Last` displays weird result `WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1+Fruit Trees`.  How can I display the proper tree name according to its position through the button clicks?

**Code**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public class ListOfTrees
        {
            private int size;

            public ListOfTrees()
            {
                size = 0;
            }

            public int Count
            {
                get { return size; }
            }

            public FruitTrees First;
            public FruitTrees Last;




        }


        public void ShowTrees()
        {

        }



        public void Current_Tree()
        {
            labelSpecificTree.Text = Trees.First.Type.ToString();
        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Current_Tree();
        }

        private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Current = Trees.First;
            labelSpecificTree.Text = Current.Next.Type.ToString();
        }

        private void buttonLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Current = Trees.Last;
            labelSpecificTree.Text = Trees.Last.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems in your code (see the comments for corrections):

```
        public int Add(FruitTrees NewItem)
        {
            FruitTrees Sample = new FruitTrees();
            Sample = NewItem;
            Sample.Next = First;
            First = Sample;
            //Last = First.Next;
            // Since Add is an  operation that prepends to the list - only update
            // Last for the first time:
            if (Last == null){
              Last = First;
            }

            return size++;
        }
```

Secondly in your Next method:

```
    private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // In order to advance you need to take into account the current position
        // and not set it to first...
        //Current = Trees.First;
        Current = Current.Next != null ? Current.Next : Current;
        labelSpecificTree.Text = Current.Type.ToString();
    }
```

And in the "last" method:

```
    private void buttonLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Current = Trees.Last;
        // show the data, not the name of the Type
        labelSpecificTree.Text = Current.Type.ToString();
    }
```

And of course the current method is broken, also...

```
    public void Current_Tree()
    {
        Current = Trees.First;
        labelSpecificTree.Text = Current.Type.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: +1 Now It gives me a `NullReferenceException` for this line in button `Next` `Current = Current.Next != null ? Current.Next : Current;` saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: Thank you. Almost perfect, Now when I start form and click button `Last` Nothing displays? I am not sure since everything seems correct

Comment: @codexMachine23: For problems like this, (and actually the first problems, too), you should really try a debugger, if you cannot see the problem immediately just by looking at the code. I did not run your code, so I cannot debug it. I don't see, what the problem might be. For problems like this, you might refer to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than SO...

Comment: I am doing something identical but my question is a little more restructured, Please check: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863114/show-position-of-item-in-a-link-list)