# Show position of item in a list

Tags: c#

I am working with a link list. My constructor takes arrays with items in it or appends an item(one at time) to the list through `BtnAddTree` click. For experimental reasons I am trying to figure out a way to retrieve the position of an item from the list. I have set three buttons that will hopefully show: `first`, `next`, `last` item and display through a `label`. I created two functions to achieve my need `Retrieve` and `Current_Tree()` but here is where I come to a dead end. I am aware to display items that are `next` I may need to use a loop but unsure how to go about it. How can I display the position of an item found in the list?

```
        public class ListForTrees
        {

        //Retrieve Position of item
            public void Retrieve(int Position)
            {
                int new_position = Position;
                fruit_trees current = first_tree;

                for (int i = 0; i < Position && current != null; i++)
                {
                    current = current.next_tree;
                }
                return current;
            }

        //Show Current Tree
            public void Current_Tree()
            {
                try
                {
                    current = fruit_trees.first_tree;
                    labelSpecificTree.Text = current.Type.ToString();
                }
                catch { };

            }         



        }

        ListForTrees mainlist = new ListForTrees();     

        private void BtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fruit_trees[] ax = {   new fruit_trees("cherry", 48, 12.95, 3),
                                             new fruit_trees("pine", 36, 9.95, 8),
                                             new fruit_trees("oak", 60, 14.95, 2),
                                             new fruit_trees("peach", 54, 19.95, 3),
                                             new fruit_trees("pear", 36, 11.85, 2),
                                             new fruit_trees("apple", 62, 13.45, 5)
                                         };   
            mainlist = new ListForTrees(ax);
            fruit_trees current = mainlist.first_tree;   

            while (current != null)
            {
                TxtOutput.AppendText(current.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                current = current.next_tree;
            }
        }

        private void ShowNextItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //Show Next Item
        }

        private void ShowLastItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //Show Last Item
        }

        private void ShowFirstItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // Show First Item
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If you plan on setting/retrieving entries based on an index value, perhaps you should reconsider using a linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Develop a way to compare the object properly.  is tree type unique?  maybe you need a full icomparable?

then create a method in the listoftrees class

```
public int getPosition(fruit_trees tree)
{
 fruit_trees ft = first_tree;
 if(ft.tree_type == tree.tree_type)
 {
      return 0; //or return 1 depending on how you want to index stuff
 }
 int i = 1;//possibly set to 2 if returning 1 above
 while(ft.next_tree != null)
 {
     ft = ft.next_tree;
     if(ft.tree_type == tree.tree_type)
     {
        return i; 
     }
     i++;
 }

 return -1; //or something else here to show that its not in the list

}
```

also as a side note ..Dont set the label value in the class in the method Current_Tree().  That should return a fruit_trees object and the btn click methods should set the label value .

you should actually just get rid of that method completely(unless there is some reason for it outside of the code above.

Comment: +1 Great answer, I have taken out that uneccessary method. I have implemented your `getPosition` but it is showing  `tree_type` innaccesible due to its protection level. how come?

Comment: because its marked as a private member.  Either make public or create a public method like 

    public string GetTreeType() that just returns the tree_type in the fruit_trees class

Comment: Alright thankyou, Could you show me the rest: how would i be able to call it from button so it displays First, Next, Last tree through a label.

Comment: First off what is next?  The one after first?  you dont have a member that is holding the current fruit_tree  either add and int member or another fruit_tree member called current.  You see you are only storing the first and last trees and have nothing to tell you what the current or next tree is.    as for the code to display to a label ... labelSpecificTree.Text = ax.firstTree.tree_type;  ... put that in the first btn event and then do similar thing for the last ... as for the next, you need to develop a way to know what is current

Comment: Yes next is the one after first. but alright you answered all the questions. i may have to post another question shortly. ill keep you update if you wan to give it a try.

Comment: My new question: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868380/determening-the-currently-pointed-to-item-in-a-list)