# Determining the currently pointed to item in a list

Tags: c#

I am working with lists. I have been able to determine the first and last position of items in my list. I am using `getPostion` and displaying item name through a `Label`. Three buttons in my form: `ShowFirstItem` `ShowNextItem`(not working) and `ShowLastItem` show the corresponding item in a label. I am having problems for my next item. I don't have a member that is holding the current `fruit_tree`. So I am not sure how to either add an `int` member or another `fruit_tree` member called `current`. How would I be able to find out next (item after first) and display result?

```
 public class ListForTrees
 {

        public fruit_trees GetNextTree()
            {
                current = 0;
                fruit_trees ft = first_tree;
                int i = 0;
                while (i != current)
                {
                    ft = ft.next_tree;
                    i++;

                }

                return ft;
            }

            }

            ListForTrees mainlist = new ListForTrees();     

            private void BtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                fruit_trees[] ar_items = {   new fruit_trees("cherry", 48, 12.95, 3),
                                                 new fruit_trees("pine", 36, 9.95, 8),
                                                 new fruit_trees("oak", 60, 14.95, 2),
                                                 new fruit_trees("peach", 54, 19.95, 3),
                                                 new fruit_trees("pear", 36, 11.85, 2),
                                                 new fruit_trees("apple", 62, 13.45, 5)
                                             };   
                mainlist = new ListForTrees(ar_items);
                fruit_trees current = mainlist.first_tree;   

                while (current != null)
                {
                    TxtOutput.AppendText(current.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                    current = current.next_tree;
                }
            }


            private void ShowFirstItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            // Show First Item
        labelSpecificTree.Text = mainlist.first_tree.GetTreeType;

            } 

            private void ShowLastItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            //Show Last Item
        labelSpecificTree.Text = mainlist.last_tree.GetTreeType;
            }

        private void ShowNextItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            //Show Next Item
 fruit_trees obj = mainlist.GetNextTree();

            if (obj == null)
            {
                labelSpecificTree.Text = "No more trees!";
            }
            else
            {
                mainlist.current++;
                labelSpecificTree.Text = obj.next_tree.GetTreeType.ToString();                
            }   
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add

```
public int current;
```

to the listoftrees.  in the constructor set it to 0;

Then create a method to return the current fruit_trees object

```
public fruit_trees getCurrent()
{
    fruit_trees ft = first_tree;
    int i = 0;   
    while(i != current)
    {
       ft = ft.next_tree;
       i++;
    }
    return ft;
 }
```

now this method returns the current and not the next object.  So you have 2 options in the next button event.
the quesiton here is do you want to move to the next tree object every time the button is clicked? 
if so increment the current property and then call getcurrent to display.  If you want the current to be retained and not move (i.e. clicking next over and over will result in the same thing) 
then display getcurrent().next_tree.tree_type with no increment to current.

Comment: yes, good. I am trying to move to the next tree object in the list. From the button click would I have  to increment `current++`? or exactly how will i do it?

Comment: mainlist.current++; 

after that call the next call to getCurrent() would have the next tree_object

Comment: Alright, I added the increment `mainlist.current++` and then called  `getCurrent` (in my case changed it to `GetNextTree`) inside the button but i am getting only one tree after first and nothing else. I have edited the code to the new changes. Please check my question.

Comment: you are setting current=0 in the wrong place ... that should be done in the constructor of listoftreest not in getnexttree ... it should be put in both public ListForTrees(fruit_trees new_tree) and  public ListForTrees(IEnumerable<fruit_trees> trees)   ... see you are resetting the current to 0 everytime you call to get next (cause you to get the same tree no matter the previous value of current.

Comment: Now that works! Last matter: once it hits the last tree i get an error. How can I make it point back out to `first_tree`?

Comment: in the getnexttree method you will want to place a check at the start ... something like if(current == count)   then set current to 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves Your issue, but You can add

```
public fruit_trees current_tree;
```

field in `ListForTrees` class.

Then, You can easily add method showing next and moving item pointer to the next item in the list. Remembering the current item allows You to avoid browsing the whole list each time You want next tree from the list.
The code can look like this:

```
public fruit_trees GetNextTree()
{
    //save currently pointed tree
    fruit_trees tree = this.current_tree;
    if (tree != null)
    {
        //move current_tree to the next tree, to be returned next time
        current_tree = current_tree.next_tree;
        //return saved tree object
    }
    return tree;
}
```

In order to make it work, You should also remember to initiate the value of `current_tree` with the first tree added to the list. You can also write some kind of `ResetNextTreePointer()` method pointing it back to the first tree in the list.

Some more suggestions to the code:

- I suppose it would be better to use properties for fields in your classes, so i.e. change

  ```
  public fruit_trees first_tree;
  ```

  into

  ```
  private fruit_trees first_tree;
  public fruit_trees First_tree { get { return first_tree; }
  ```

  as it would disable any class outside your class to modify those fields explicitly.
- This code:

  ```
  if (count == 0)
  {
      ...
  }
  else if (count != 0)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

  can be changed into:

  ```
  if (count == 0)
  {
      ...
  }
  else
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: +1 This is perfect. Almost working, how would i call exactly `GetNextTree` from `ShowNextItem` button to display in label?

Comment: If you just implement it as `labelSpecificTree.Text = mainlist.GetNextTree();`, it will give You next tree from the list on each click.

Comment: I tried it that way but its giving me error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'TreeFarm.Form1.fruit_trees' to 'string'`

Comment: My mistake. You should just write a string property (or field) You want to display i.e. `labelSpecificTree.Text = mainlist.GetNextTree().GetTreeType;`.