# Classes & Constructors: Incrementing a variable outside class

Tags: c#

I am currently working with classes and constructors. I have sint variable named `current` that equals `0` inside the constructor. Now when I click the button I am trying to increment property `current` and then call GetNextTree to display. But when incrementing `current++` from button click I receive this error: `does not exist in current context`. What would be the proper way to increment `current` then?

```
public class fruit_trees
    {

    } 
public class ListForTrees
        {
    public int current;

    public fruit_trees GetNextTree()
            {
                current = 0;
                fruit_trees ft = first_tree;
                int i = 0;
                while (i != current)
                {
                    ft = ft.next_tree;
                    i++;

                }

                return ft;

            }


    }

private void ShowNextItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Show Last Item

            fruit_trees obj = mainlist.GetNextTree();


            if (obj == null)
            {
                labelSpecificTree.Text = "No more trees!";
            }
            else
            {
               //error: current does not exist?
        current++
                labelSpecificTree.Text = obj.next_tree.GetTreeType.ToString();

            }   

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the scope (encapsulation) where you try to call `int current`.

From your posted code, `int current` is defined in `class ListForTrees`. However you are trying to access it without initializing your object of type ListForTrees.

In addition, you are using `mainlist` which is also not defined in your posted code. Please, post complete code coverage of items that you use in code.

Comment: This questiosn is branched to this [ONE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863114/show-position-of-item-in-a-list/13863661#13863661). It has the complete code. Unsure how to branch questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `current` variable is encapsulated inside your `ListForTrees` class. Since this variable is an instance variable, you need to create a new instance of `ListForTrees` in order to access this variable using the `instance.variable` syntax.

Moreover I believe your class design is quite flawed. I think what you should redesign your class like:

```
public class FruitTree
{
    public static int Current { get; set; }
    public FruitTree GetNextTree()
    {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

And then you can initialize a list of trees in your code